# how to get values from edit text without using xml code

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created edittext and textview without using xml attributes i have defined in java file only but i am unable get values entered in edittext how to get values.i have 2 edittexts if user enters the values i should add the values

```
public class JavacodeActivity extends Activity {
    LinearLayout layout;
    TextView view;
    EditText edit;
    Button btn;
    EditText edit1;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        layout=new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        view=new TextView(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.setText("enter the value");
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        view.setTextSize(20);
        layout.addView(view);

        edit1=new EditText(this);
        edit1.setLayoutParams(new  LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        edit1.setHint("enter the number");
        edit1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        edit1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        edit1.setTextSize(20);
        edit1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        layout.addView(edit1);

        btn=new Button(this);
        btn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btn.setText("add");
        btn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        btn.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        btn.setTextSize(20);
        layout.addView(btn);

        view=new TextView(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        view.setText("addition of values");
        view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        view.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        view.setTextSize(20);
        layout.addView(view);
```

I don't know the attribute to retrieve values from `edittext` if the code is java I am unable to retrieve values. Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean editText.getText().toString();

Comment: @RKN and mango. Thank you, this is so much easier to read!

Answer (score 4):

> I don't know the attribute to retrieve values from edittext if the code is java I am unable to retrieve values

Read your EditText like any other EditText:

```
String text = edit.getText().toString();
```